# How to get multiple documents from one document in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have multiple documents that needs to be queried from mongodb. Requirement is such that I need the nested array of documents has to be in a separate document under certain conditions. I have given a document sample for instance. In that I have an array of objects called `cars`, the output have to be such that the `status` is still `inprogress` and the key: `parent_company` is `true` then the objects that has `parent_company_id` equal to the `_id` of the `parent_company: true` and at least one of their `model` array has `"v12"`.
This might be confusing when explaining but please check on the document in db and the expected result, you'd get an idea on the requirement here.

If you take a look at the second JSON below, you can see those are the same Documents with different array of cars with certain conditions and that is how am expecting the results to be from the actual data from a collection
So the condition is `status` has to be `"inprogress"` for  `"parent_company" : true` and if any object under `cars` array has `v12` in `model` then I need to get those documents that has the same `parent_company_id`.

Documents in db:

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a8808652f40e1d48a3d1d7"),
    "name" : "A",
    "description" : null,
    "cars" : [
        {
            "id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "owner" : "John Doe",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "inprogress",
            "parent_company" : true,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "model" : [
              
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880a552f40e1d48a3d1dc",
            "owner" : "John Doe 1",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_company" : false,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "model" : [
               "v12"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48assddd"
            "owner" : "John Doe 1",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_company" : false,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "model" : [
              
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207"
            "owner" : "John Doe 11",
            "dt" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "inprogress",
            "parent_company" : true,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207",
            "model" : [
               "v12"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfddd"
            "owner" : "John Doe 112",
            "dt" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "inprogress",
            "parent_company" : true,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfddd",
            "model" : [
              
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result I need

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a8808652f40e1d48a3d1d7"),
    "name" : "A",
    "description" : null,
    "cars" : [
        {
            "id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "owner" : "John Doe",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "inprogress",
            "parent_company" : true,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "model" : [
              
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880a552f40e1d48a3d1dc",
            "owner" : "John Doe 1",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_company" : false,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "model" : [
               "v12"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48assddd"
            "owner" : "John Doe 1",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_company" : false,
            "parent_company_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "model" : [
              
            ]
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63a8808652f40e1d48a3d1d7"),
    "name" : "A",
    "description" : null,
    "cars" : [
        {
           "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207"
           "owner" : "John Doe 11",
           "dt" : "2022-12-25,
           "status" : "inprogress",
           "parent_company" : true,
           "parent_company_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207",
           "model" : [
              "v12"
             ]
            }
    ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Why is the last element in the `"cars"` array completely missing in the result? Do you want to filter and partition?  If so, what is the filter? ... What is the partition?

Comment: Filter is - First get an object in the car array that has `status: "inprogress"` and also the `parent_company : true`, then once this is done we have to match it's `parent_company_id` with other objects and get the objects that has same `parent_company_id` and from the above result of these any one of the objects should definitely have `"v12"` in model array.
Partition is - the above result array of objects should be in different documents with same _id, name, description and cars just like the result am expecting(as shown above).

Comment: the reason why last element is missing because it does not satisfy the condition am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here's one way to do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$unwind": "$cars"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$cars.parent_company_id",
      "root": {"$first": "$$ROOT"},
      "cars": {"$push": "$cars"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": [
        "$root",
        {"cars": "$cars"}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "cars.parent_company": true,
      "cars.model": "v12"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x07qduHPP1X).

Comment: The result seems to be wrong. For the **0th** index object in the result, the car array has an object at **3rd** index that has different `parent_company_id` compared to the other 3 objects within the car array. It actually wasn't supposed to be there.https://mongoplayground.net/p/O2DCwznv8o6

Comment: @BlackWooDZZ I guess I didn't understand your partition logic correctly.  Is the `mongoplayground.net` link in your comment correct?  If so, you could post it as an answer.

Comment: No the query I tried did not work as well, the partition is such that -
**car** array objects that has **parent_company_id** same and model has **v12** in the array 
and if the **parent_company** is true then the status should in **inprogress** and also it's **id** has to match with the **parent_company_id** from the above.

Comment: @BlackWooDZZ  I've update my answer to hopefully match your filter and partition logic.